Unable to replace address values of a dataset using Places API
I had a problem with replacing the original values of the address column with the address I get from Places API response. Even though the code and its responses were smooth-sailing, something must have gone awry with the data.loc[i,add_col]=address since the dataset remains the same after applying this function
import googlemaps
import win32com.client as win32

API_KEY = "(MY API KEY)"
map_client = googlemaps.Client(API_KEY)

def replace_address(data,add_col):
    if data[add_col].notna().any():
        data = data[data[add_col].notna()]
        for i in data.index:
            location_name = data.loc[i,add_col]
            response = map_client.places(query=location_name)

            if response['status'] == 'OK':
                places = response['results']
                place=places[0]
                name = place['name']
                address = place.get('formatted_address', 'Address not available')
                print(f"id: {i}, Query:{location_name}, Name: {name}, Address: {address}")
                data.loc[i,add_col]=address
            else:
                print("No places found or error occurred:", response['status'])
    else:
        pass

df_replace_add = data[data[["Huyện","Quận"]].isnull().sum(axis=1)==1]
replace_address(df_replace_add,"Địa chỉ")

df_replace_add still remains the same even when I change .loc() to .iloc() with the corresponding indexer. I have been struggling with this for hours yet not figuring out how to solve it. Any assistance is much appreciated T.T

Updated: I also received a warning. Does this have anything to do with the problem:

SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
data.loc[i,add_col]=address

because replace_address has a local copy of the dataframe -- to update it outside of the function scope you should return the new dataframe in the function and update the df_replace_add dataframe with it

Im not sure what you mean by this, can you elaborate on this? At which line of code causes the error?
BTW, for my new code block, it actually worked as I wish, is that because I did not make the copy data = data[data[add_col].notna()]?
/*
def replace_address(data,add_col):
for i in data.index:
    if not pd.isna(data.loc[i, add_col]): 
        location_name = data.loc[i, add_col]
    elif pd.isna(data.loc[i, add_col]) and not pd.isna(data.loc[i, "Huyện"]):
        location_name = data.loc[i, "Huyện"]
    else:
        continue

....
*/

Here is the new code block that works, is that because I did not make the copy data = data[data[add_col].notna()] or else?
def replace_address(data,add_col):

    for i in data.index:
        if not pd.isna(data.loc[i, add_col]): 
            location_name = data.loc[i, add_col]
        elif pd.isna(data.loc[i, add_col]) and not pd.isna(data.loc[i, "Huyện"]):
            location_name = data.loc[i, "Huyện"]
        else:
            continue
        response = map_client.places(query=location_name)

        if response['status'] == 'OK':
            places = response['results']
            place=places[0]
            name = place['name']
            address = place.get('formatted_address', 'Address not available')
            print(f"id: {i}, Query:{location_name}, Name: {name}, Address: {address}")
            data.loc[data[add_col]==location_name,add_col]=address
        else:
            print("No places found or error occurred:", response['status'])


df_replace_add = data[data[["Huyện","Quận"]].isnull().sum(axis=1)==1]
replace_address(df_replace_add,"Địa chỉ")

Also quoted below is another way I just found out, Thanks to @Andrew Ryan
def replace_address(data, add_col):
    if data[add_col].notna().any():
        global updated_data
        updated_data = data[data[add_col].notna()]
        for i in updated_data.index:
            location_name = updated_data.loc[i, add_col]
            response = map_client.places(query=location_name)

            if response['status'] == 'OK':
                places = response['results']
                place = places[0]
                name = place['name']
                address = place.get('formatted_address', 'Address not available')
                print(f"id: {i}, Query: {location_name}, Name: {name}, Address: {address}")
                updated_data.loc[i, add_col] = address
            else:
                print("No places found or error occurred:", response['status'])
    else:
        pass

df_replace_add = data[data[["Huyện", "Quận"]].isnull().sum(axis=1) == 1]
df_replace_add = replace_address(df_replace_add, "Địa chỉ") 

